# Unable to pass input data from a react-autosuggest to a parent file

Tags: reactjs

Hye, i'm new in React and i try to get input from a react-autosuggest component to a parent file:

parent component SearchBar:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Searchbar.css';
import SearchButtons from './buttons/SearchButtons';
import SearchInput from './input/AutoSuggestInput';

class SearchBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      inputValue: '',
    };
  }

  getValue = (newValue) => {
    this.setState({ inputValue: newValue });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="searchBarItems">
        <SearchInput getValue={(event, value) => this.getValue(event, value)} />
        <SearchButtons />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchBar;
```

child component SearchInput with auto-suggest:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './AutoSuggestInput.css';
import Autosuggest from 'react-autosuggest';
import cities from '../../../../assets/citiesDB/cities';

function escapeRegexCharacters(str) {
  return str.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
}

function getSuggestions(value) {
  const escapedValue = escapeRegexCharacters(value.trim());

  if (escapedValue === '') {
    return [];
  }

  const regex = new RegExp(escapedValue, 'i');

  return cities.filter((city) => regex.test(city.name));
}

function getSuggestionValue(suggestion) {
  return (suggestion.name);
}

function renderSuggestion(suggestion) {
  return (
    <span>{suggestion.name}</span>
  );
}

class SearchInput extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      value: '',
      suggestions: [],
    };
  }

  onChange = (event, { newValue }) => {
    this.setState({
      value: newValue,
    });
    this.props.getValue(event, newValue);
  };

  onSuggestionsFetchRequested = ({ value }) => {
    this.setState({
      suggestions: getSuggestions(value),
    });
  };

  onSuggestionsClearRequested = () => {
    this.setState({
      suggestions: [],
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { value, suggestions } = this.state;
    const inputProps = {
      placeholder: 'Saisir une ville',
      value,
      onChange: this.onChange,
    };

    return (
      <Autosuggest
        suggestions={suggestions}
        onSuggestionsFetchRequested={this.onSuggestionsFetchRequested}
        onSuggestionsClearRequested={this.onSuggestionsClearRequested}
        getSuggestionValue={getSuggestionValue}
        renderSuggestion={renderSuggestion}
        inputProps={inputProps}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default SearchInput;
```

I have 2 problems:

src\components\homepage\searchBar\SearchBar.jsx
Line 12:7:   Unused state field: 'inputValue'  react/no-unused-state
Line 17:21:  Unused state field: 'inputValue'  react/no-unused-state

src\components\homepage\searchBar\input\AutoSuggestInput.jsx
Line 46:5:   Must use destructuring props assignment    react/destructuring-assignment
Line 46:16:  'getValue' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types

Someone could help me please ? I don't understand why it's unused

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly as React said, your state `inputValue` has been set, but you're not using it anywhere or for any actions. You can get rid of it when using the `inputValue` state.

For example, put it in `render()` method of `SearchBar` component:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="searchBarItems">
        <SearchInput getValue={(event, value) => this.getValue(event, value)} />
        <SearchButtons />
        <p>Current input value: {this.state.inputValue}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

---

The second problem, its linting error, said that you should restructure the props, and you can get rid of that like below:

```
onChange = (event, { newValue }) => {
    this.setState({
      value: newValue,
    });
    const { getValue } = this.props;
    getValue(event, newValue);
  };
```

Comment: ok thanks but i call it in my setstate, i thought it was right. And what about my getValue missing props, what i make wrong ?

Comment: Actually, `setState` means you update the state of the component. So, it's not really is using the state. The state laid out there and not used for any action. That's why React yell at you.

Comment: @nicolasmoreau I updated the answer for the 2nd problem. Please check and upvote for me if you think it's helpful :D